# How to tell msbuild, that it needs to publish to new directory and adjust IIS to it?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy

Currently we have following structure:

```
web
    build0001
    build0002
    build0003
```

So, each time we deploy new version of web application, we create folder with build number and then change path in IIS to use that directory.
Now question is, can I do same thing with msbuild:
1) publish to `web\buildxxxx`
2) and update IIS setting to use `web\buildxxxx` for that site.

While currently I doing all this in same server, in the future I'll need to do this on remote servers also, meaning that I'll running msbuild from different server than IIS is.

So far I've came to this:

> "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"^
>    -verb:sync^
>    -source:contentPath="c:\stageDir"^
>    -dest:contentPath="c:\web\build0004",computername="https://remoteServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=MySite",UserName="DeployUser",Password="xxx",authType=Basic^
>    -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule^
>    -allowUntrusted^
>    -postSync:runCommand="C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set vdir MySite/ -physicalPath:c:\web\build0004"

Problem with this approach is, that is requires a lot of permissions, because of these things:

1. build0004 at the moment of syncing is out of current website's folder (say build0003), so it requires DeployUser to have administrative rights.
2. I need ability to use runCommand, which requires even more - allow WMSVC to run commands.

Comment: You used msdeploy tag, then why not add Web Deploy to your CI script, http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy and then you can package different versions of the web app, and deploy them to IIS as you wish.

Comment: I've updated my question with approach that I have and the problems that it is causing.